# Django tutorial: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls\\/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']

Tags: django

I was following the Django tutorial when I got this problem.
I tried to copy paste and to read the tutorial again and again but I can't fix it.

The error is: "Reverse for 'detail' not found. 'detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Error Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/

Django Version: 2.0.3
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['polls',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/cristian/Desktop/build/polls/templates/polls/index.html, error at line 1
   Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls\\/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
   1 : <li><a href=" {% url 'detail' question.id %} ">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>

Traceback:

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/cristian/Desktop/build/polls/views.py" in index
  10.     return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  447.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  88.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/home/cristian/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  632.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /polls/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls\\/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Choice, Question

    def index(request):
        latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
        context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
        return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

    def detail(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})

    def results(request, question_id):
        question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
        return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
```

models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

index.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action={% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

I hope that you can help me, thanks.

Comment: can you copy and paste the full error traceback?

Comment: Sure, I added it, I hope that is what you meant.

Comment: Paste here `index.html` complete

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the index.html

```
<li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
```

Remove the url detail in the index.html and put it in details.html. As you can see the url dispatcher doesn't find your url because there is no poll id available.

Comment: Adding {% for question in latest_question_list %} and {% endfor %} worked. The tutorial wasn't very clear, anyway thanks for helping me, I will join the telegram group.